# Bamboo build Tag not including branch name

Tags: bamboo

I am successfully creating a Git tag from bamboo but need to add the branch name to the tag and not just the build number and I cannot get it to work. This is the script that works for just the build number as the tag name:

```
git tag -f -a ${bamboo.buildNumber} -m "${bamboo.planName} build number ${bamboo.buildNumber} passed automated acceptance testing." ${bamboo.planRepository.revision}
git remote add central ${bamboo.planRepository.repositoryUrl}
git push central ${bamboo.buildNumber}
git ls-remote --exit-code --tags central ${bamboo.buildNumber}
```

I have tried defining a variable including the bamboo.buildNumber and bamboo.repository.branch.name and that did not work either in the plan variables or in the build and package task script. I also added the bamboo.repository.branch.name variable to the git tag line in the script and that didn't work either.

The problem with the tag just being the build number is it can overlap with other tag names if multiple branches are using the same Bamboo plan. Also a tag should reference the branch it was created from.

Comment: `bamboo.shortPlanBranchName` is not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you use newer version of Bamboo, it might has ${bamboo.repository.branch.name} variable deprecated. Try using this one: **${bamboo.planRepository.branchName}**

Comment: This variable is working for me!  The documentation is just wrong:  https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-variables-289277087.html